# Out-Of-Browser Service Access problem using Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser, wcf-data-services

I have a Silverlight 4 application that access a couple of WCF Data Services.

There are no problems accessing the service through the browser.

I set the program to run out-of-browser with elevated trust.  Then I can see the calls to the WCF Service via fiddler, but nothing ever comes back.

If I debug then I get the following error:

```
$exception  {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckThread()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.GetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp)
   at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.get_CountImpl()
   at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.get_Count()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.IItemContainerGenerator.RemoveAll()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.RemoveAll()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnRefresh()
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.System.Windows.Controls.ICollectionChangedListener.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.WeakCollectionChangedListener.SourceCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.System.Windows.Controls.ICollectionChangedListener.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.WeakCollectionChangedListener.SourceCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.ClearItems()
   at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Clear()
   at ClientFolderExplorer.ViewModels.DocumentExplorerViewModel.clientCatalog_ClientsLoadingComplete(Object sender, ClientLoadingEventArgs e)
   at ClientFolderExplorer.Catalogs.ClientCatalog.<>c__DisplayClass3.<ExecuteClientQuery>b__2(IAsyncResult a)}  System.Exception {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}
```

Not sure where to start troubleshooting.  I have `crossdomain.xml` and `clientaccesspolicy.xml` files in place in the root of the webserver, but I cannot even see these files being requested (in fiddler).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - you suppose the problem is related to cross-site access, while in reality it's related to cross-**thread** access (first line of error indicates this clearly).

I'm assuming you're trying to set some UI element's data bound (or not, doesn't matter) property directly from the callback handling the service call. (edit) Forgot to clarify - where the callback is running on a thread different from the UI thread. Silverlight like most other frameworks disallows modifying UI except from the UI thread.

If so, take a look at how to use `Dispatcher` in order to switch back to the UI thread.

Comment: It doesn't get that far, as the "data loading error" is fired.  My callback method does use dispatcher but doesn't ever get fired.  Once again, this only happens out of browser so unless there are some extra threading things to take into account here, I am still confused as to what is causing the problem :-(

Comment: I just looked at the problem again. Since you're running OOB, I don't see why would SL ever ask for cross domain file since *technically* your app is not coming from any domain. The fact that these files are not requested is thus normal. What's also for sure is that this is a cross-threading problem. Looking at the call stack, I can see that ObservableCollection is being changed, which is more than likely bound to the UI, which will ultimately fail. However, the beggining of the call statck is not that readable since you're using anonymous method there.

Comment: If you could provide a small isolated test case, it might be easier to figure this out. Try to cut out everything not related to the bug in question, then post just the problematic code.

Comment: I've got it..... I was using:
Application.Current.RootVisual.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                                                  {
                                                                      OnErrorLoading(e.Error);
                                                                  });
Which was fine in the browser but failed out of browser.....

System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {......

Worked however.

Thanks for pointing me in th righ direction!

Comment: Not really sure why one failed OOB only though!

Comment: Hey, glad to hear you've resolved this. Frankly, I'm puzzled that there are (or appears to be) two Dispatchers?!? In some of my projects since I ported code from older .NET versions we used SynchronizationContext so I can't say I've used Dispatcher much. I agree with you that this is weird.